# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. - Only when no "https://" is entered. Windows IIS with Wordpress. - Any ideas?

Tags: ssl, https, iis, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS.  I have added a website at the following address:  https://List4Less.com

It worked fine up until recently.  I added a wildcard SSL certificate and it works fine as long as I include "https://" in front of the List4Less.com.  If I leave the protocol section off, then I get "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

I have removed the bindings to http.  In addition, I set up a URL Rewrite to redirect any http to https.

I wish I could tell you all of the things I have tried, but I simply can't remember everything.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem myself.  Since I had removed the port 80 bindings, there was no where to redirect from.  Once I added the http (port 80) bindings back in and then opened a browser and entered the domain name without any prefix protocol, the redirect to https worked perfectly.

Thank you for anyone that was pondering this issue.  I hope this helps others with this issue.

Take Care!